# Write a MySQL join query for retrieve project information

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, create-table

I need to write a MySQL join query for retrieve project information as this image below.

[image]

project manager able to get list of each developer's `workingHours, Overtime, Descriptions, Contributions` for specific project his assigned. This is my database table structure.

Can anyone tell me how to to this? I need output like this image using this table structure.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at this post:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions